# Limit the number of threads for one java command

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, system

I have to run several java program that **I can't edit** (student programs).

I would like to set a limit on the number of threads such program can create (otherwise, they can fill my server with lot of threads). 
I didn't find a solution so far.

`ulimit -T` seems not implemented on debian.
I'm also OK if there is a solution to limit the number of threads of a specific user.

Comment: Can you please share code ?

Comment: Which code ? I run the java programs with java -jar program.jar (and program.jar can create lot of threads if they want)

Comment: Ok I see, why don't you handle this on these programs ?

Comment: Because I can't edit these programs.

Comment: There is no such command to restrict no.of threads. But programmatically you can restrict If you have the source code.

Comment: I think you're more concerned with CPU utilization than number of threads. The Java process could create a thousand threads, but if they're all idle, who cares? (Obviously you might care for a production system, but these are student programs.) I suggest you use Docker to run each Java process in a separate container and limit the CPU available to each.

Comment: Also see [What are the useful JVM options for a multithreaded application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12581337/608639) and [jvm man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/java-java-1.7.0-openjdk) It appears the only thread count you can control is the number of parallel GC threads by using `ParallelGCThreads`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [`prlimit -u`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/prlimit.1.html) is what I was looking for.